# Bingbot is encoding non-ASCII characters in URLs with backslash x rather than percent

Tags: url-encoding, tomcat, bingbot

We have hashbang urls with extended utf-8 characters.  For example:

```
https://example.com/#!каталог
```

Bing bot fetches the html snapshot [https://example.com?_escaped_fragment_=каталог](https://example.com?_escaped_fragment_=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3) encoded URL as `\xD0\xB0...`.   Our server responded with a 400 error for that. They only accept percent encoded URLs.  `%D0%B0...` would get a 200 OK status.

How can I resolve this problem?

for example: [image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a real Bingbot? I have seen (in sever logs) many poorly written bots that pretend to be e.g. Googlebot.

Comment: pic added [updated]. IP check: https://dig.whois.com.au/ip/40.77.167.196

Comment: could it be be a kind, how your tomcat handles urls, not?

Answer (score 5):

You should encode the image name before giving it to crawl for any bots, i.e. the image name should be as `%2F%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3.jpg` in your page source code.
All modern browser decode it and for users will show the UTF-8 characters in a human-friendly way.

So, do server-side encoding and encode all these characters before including in your source code.

View the source code for this  Wikipedia page and you will understand:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9D

Update:
Based on deeper review the website and other StackExchange users comments below. It looks that you must encode all of your URLs in your website and XML sitemap. In your website, you don't have encoded URLs, as well not encoded URLs in XML sitemap. Please use UTF-8 encoded URLs everywhere.
Keep in mind, that Bingbot is way behind Googlebot and just recently started to render JS based website in more wider scale. Using non-ASCII characters could cause bugs for Bingbot.

The URLs in your source code and DOM, as well in your XML sitemap must be encoded like this based on your example:

```
https://example.com/#!%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3
```

Here you can read more about proper sitemap encoding: https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping

Comment: You think they are linking to `зураг.jpg` rather than `%D0%B7ураг.jpg` ?

Comment: Yes, I assume, that in the source code the image name is: зураг.jpg

Comment: tnx @gintsg, but it's not only for image path. It's about all paths. for example image, hashfragment, etc. Our project based on Spring boot, vaadin8, embeded tomcat, nginx /plesk onyx/ [our project](https://negdoor.mn/#!төмөр-хүлэг/)

Comment: @ts.tsogtgerel thanks for sharing your website. Now everything is clear. The main issue is, that your website is in JS and Bing is extremely new to rendering JS content and index JS based website. Google is pretty advanced with rendering JS files and see content pretty good, but Bing is a newbie here. Maybe you can talk with your team about an option to prerender your content or something? Here is a pretty good guide about JS rendered [websites](https://www.elephate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-javascript-seo/) This information will give you a lot of information about the issue.

Comment: @ts.tsogtgerel additional note. In your website DOM, I can see, that your URLs is not encoded as well. But in your case, Bing bot even can't see your content.

Comment: "The main issue is, that your website is in JS" - The JS element could hamper Bing from crawling/indexing the site to begin with, but this should not be the reason for Bing crawling the _incorrectly encoded URLs_. (?) Incidentally, it seems the unencoded URLs are present in the XML sitemap as well, which I imagine is probably being submitted to Bing's Webmaster Tools?

Comment: yes, of course @MrWhite, we submitted our sitemap.xml to bing webmaster tool. Bing bot know our site is ajax and call html snapshot /_escaped_fragment_ url / correctly, but with wrong encoded. facebook and google do that correct with backslash and percent url.

Comment: @ts.tsogtgerel please see my updates on the post. Hope it will help to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `urlencode` images `src` attribute in `<img>` html tags.

Comment: This is considered a low quality answer. Can you explain your thinking more and include some details? Assume the OP has little to no idea what you are talking about. Cheers!!